# Autocomplete not working on dynamically added textBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I found code of creating dynamically textboxes by jquery and also found to implement autocomplete on a textbox by javascript.

But merging them together is a problem to me. First text box is successfully implementing autocomplete, but new dynamically created text boxes by add button do not implement autocomplete. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $(".insti_name").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<br><div><input  class="insti_name" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>

<br><br>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add_field_button "  > 
        ADD INSTITUTIONS
    </button><br>
    <div style="margin-top:11px">
        <input class="insti_name" type="text" name="mytext[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add the event handler to be bound to your class 'after' you add a new element.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete widget api does not support the dynamic behaviour you are looking out for but we can achieve the same using the below code:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        // first destroy the previously setup auto-complete
        $( ".insti_name" ).autocomplete("destroy");

        // append your new html element
        $(wrapper).append('<br><div><input  class="insti_name" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box

        // setup autocomplete again
        // you can move this call and the one above (the one you have set earlier) in one function for better maintainability
        $(".insti_name").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
        });
    }
});
```

This works for sure. Hope it helps!

Comment: @nitin please mark it as solution if it worked for you.